# Reuse function without global variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A couple of days ago I have learned on my own example how bad global variables and functions are. So apparently the best solution is NOT to use them, however sooner or later I will need to reuse my variables and functions over and over again.

So my question is: Can I reuse my functions and variables without declaring them globally? Can it be done?

For example, I want to reuse my `alertBox` function and my `containsP` variable couple of times:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ajmyZ/

```
//I am BAD GLOBAL FUNCTION inside var 
//But I am reusable!!! 

var alertBox = function () {
    alert("Hey I am BAD function!!")
}





$(document).ready(function () {
    //I am BAD GLOBAL var 
    //But I am reusable TOO!!! 
    var containsP = $("div p:first");
    containsP.click(function () {
        alert("Hi BAD var HERE!!");
    });

    $("p").eq(1).click(function () {
        alertBox();
    });

    //I am the NICEST function here
    //but I am NOT reusable :(

    $("p").eq(2).click(function () {
        alert("I am the NICEST function here!!");

    });

});
```

Comment: Those aren't global, since they're scoped to the anonymous function passed to `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Where else are you trying to use them?  Your original example of declaring them inside the ready function worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the simplest way to avoid clobbering the global object is just to create your own "application context". You can do that, by creating a self-invoking function which wraps your whole js-code within each file.

```
(function( win ) {
    "use strict";

    var still_global_but_only_in_this_anonymous_closure = true;

    $(document).ready(function() {
         // ...
         // accessing the global object:
         win.some_global_property = true;
    });
}( this ));
```

Actually, you're already creating such a local context with your anonymous function you pass into `.ready()`. This is just the more explicit way. That self-invoking method, just calls itself with the global object as argument (where you still can explicitly access global variables). Furthermore, by invoking `"use strict";` you're protected from accidently creating global variables alá `"Ops_I_Forgot_The_Var_Statment = true;`

Comment: Keep in mind that sometimes you do need global functions, and to do this inside of the wrapped function use the following:
window.myFunc = myFunc;

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has no global variables. A variable declared inside of a function (in the case of your example, the anonymous `document.ready` handler) will never be global unless you make one of two mistakes:

1. forget the `var` keyword, making an implicit global
2. explicitly say `window.myVar = ...;`